# Can I copy files from My Master-Repo Branch to My shared location using WebHooks in GIT

Tags: webhooks

I want to copy the files present in my Master repo to the shared location using Web-Hooks in GIT. How do I achieve the and where should I modify the code for that.

Thanks and regards
Prashanth